# How to get the form table name from Application Instance?

Tags: identity, identity-management, oim, identitymanager

I want to find out the process form table name from Application Instance created by some other person.
Any idea how can we get this information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the process form table name follow the steps below:

1. Login to sysadmin console
2. Search for the Application Instance
3. Get the resource object name
4. Go to design console and search for the resource object with the
   name you got
5. Check the process tab, this will give you process definition name
6. Open the process definition with the name received from process tab
7. Check the table name value